# What is the time complexity of this sorting problem?

Tags: sorting, time-complexity, complexity-theory, space-complexity

The question was given an array of n size with values ranging from [1-100]. Create a sorting algorithm and discuss it's time, space, and optimality. I don't have a decent understanding of asymptotic analysis and wasn't sure how to answer this.

Algorithm:

```c
void sort(int a[], int n) {
    int temp[100] = {0};
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        temp[a[i]-1]++;
    int c = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<temp[i]; j++) {
            a[c] = i+1;
            c++;
        }

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `O(n)`, please refer [Count Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort)